# arrayname.astype('bool') vs dtype = 'bool'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a quick question: I have used both the method `arrayname.astype('bool')` and the parameter `dtype = 'bool'` when creating an array to try convert `int` type to `bool` type. Here is how I did it:

```
booleanarray = np.array(range(10), dtype = 'bool')
print booleanarray
```

The output is:

```
[False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

Now, using `arrayname.astype('bool')`:

```
my_array = np.array(range(10))
my_array.astype('bool')
print my_array
```

The output becomes:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Why isn't the second output like the first? Why isn't `.astype()` converting the elements in my_array to bool?

Thanks!

Comment: From the documentation for [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) - ___Copy__ of the array, cast to a specified type._ This isn't done in-place.

Comment: Do you mean I need to give it a variable @mira? Like `boolarray = my_array.astype('bool')` then print boolarray? Just did this and it worked.

Comment: Yes! Exactly...

Comment: Alright! Thanks!